# Is there a way to use the name of an object to a list instead of the value of that object?

Tags: python

The best way to demonstrate is through a basic code example:

```python
aaa = 0
bbb = 0

objects_list = [aaa, bbb, aaa, bbb]

for obj in objects_list:
    obj += 1

print(aaa)
print(bbb)
```

I understand that this way when creating the loop, the list is read like this:

```
objects_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The print Terminal is:

```
0
0
```

The expected output in the terminal prints would be:

```
2
2
```

I'd like to recreate this here but in a loop:

```
aaa += 1
bbb += 1
aaa += 1
bbb += 1
```

Is there any way to create a list with object names instead of their values?

Comment: Believe you're looking for [a `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Not with integers, because integers cannot be modified.  But if you create your own class that counts things, then your first example (`objects_list = [aaa,bbb,aaa,bbb]`) would work almost exactly as you expect.

Comment: Objects don't have names in the sense of the object itself knowing what variables refer to them. Names themselves are not part of the data model, just the source code that manipulates objects.

Comment: First thank you all for the comments, i thought about creating a new clean list and using ```for i, obj in enumerate(...)``` and using the i to define the position of the value to be added, but I wanted to ask to make sure there wasn't some more "correct" way, I'll add the example in the question

Comment: @BrondbyIF that *is* the standard way to do it. Although, more idiomatic would simply be to *create a new list* using, perhaps using a list comprehension, `object_list = [x + 1 for x in object_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's int is immutable. What you are asking is saving a "pointer" to the list. This is impossible for a integer, but needs an object. Here is an example how objects work:

```
class ValueWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __iadd__(self, x):
        self.value += x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

aaa = ValueWrapper(0)
bbb = ValueWrapper(0)

objects_list = [aaa,bbb,aaa,bbb]

for obj in objects_list:
    obj += 1

print(aaa)
print(bbb)
```

Above codes give results

```
2
2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I found it very interesting, I would like to ask one last question, does this method have any limitations or risks of use or is it an option that I can use without future risks? (the friend who posted another option warned me that in the method he indicated, there may be risks of use, hence my question). Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: "What you are asking is saving a "pointer" to the list. This is impossible for a integer, but needs an object." your explanation is highly misleading. For starters, `int` objects **are objects**. And when you put an `int` in a `list`, you are effectively storing a pointer to that list object underneath the hood in *precisely the same way* as you do for your user-defined `ValueWrapper` object.

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga In that case, then wouldn't it be reliable to work with this method? Does he also end up entering the risk of use and not becoming indicated?

Comment: @BrondbyIF I do not understand your question. The above method would work fine and reliably, it just serves absolutely no good purpose and is an over-engineered solution to solve a problem that doesn't really exist.

Comment: I understand now what you meant in your message @juanpa.arrivillaga . Thank you for the informations!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you are right when you say an int is object, and list saves pointers. When I mentioned "pointer" in the answer, I mean we don't save "name" as  Brondby asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as integers are immutable, but there is a way around it:

```python
objects_list = ["aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "bbb"]   # Note that they are strings

for obj in objects_list:
    globals()[obj] += 1
```

Note that this type of programming is discouraged as it will confuse future maintainers and lead to subtle and hard to find bugs.